# Why is my very simple addition not working

Tags: python

I'm making a simple addition game that generates random numbers to add but when the answer is input it says incorrect even when it is clearly correct.
Edit: Thanks for helping. It's fixed now

```
import random
while True:
    print ("Wellcome!")
    level = input("Choose a level from 1 to 2 or type quit")
    if level == "1":
        a = random.randint (1, 10)
        b = random.randint (1, 10)
        answer = input(str(a) + " + " + str(b) + " = ")
        if answer == a + b:
            print ("Good Job!")
        else:
            print ("Incorrect")
    if level == "2":
        a = random.randint (5, 20)
        b = random.randint (5, 20)
        answer = input(str(a) + " + " + str(b) + " = ")
        if answer == a + b:
            print ("Good Job!")
        else:
            print ("Incorrect")
    if level == "quit":
        break
```

Comment: `answer` will be a string, you need to either convert it to an int or convert the result of `a + b` to a string before you compare

Comment: Let's say for example that the chosen random numbers are `3` and `5`, such that the sum is `8`. Let's say the user types `8` and presses Enter. Are you expecting that the result from `input` will be equal to the sum? Why? (Hint: when you asked the user to choose a level, you had to put `"1"` and `"2"` like that in quotes in order to compare them properly. Right? Why? What happened when you tried comparing the input to `1` and/or `2`? Why does that happen? What happened when you tried reading the documentation for `input`?)

Comment: Apart from it being a crucial step for us to be able to help you, creating a [mre] often helps you see the problem yourself. In this case, replace the inputs with hard-coded values and try to recreate the problem

Comment: @Carcigenicate Did you mean `print(type(answer), type(a + b))`? Doing `print("5", 5)` simply outputs `5 5`

Comment: @Tomerikoo Oops, you're right. That was a bad suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

Input returns a string by default. and '6' is not equal to 6.
Convert it to int with the `int` function.

```
import random
while True:
    print ("Wellcome!")
    level = input("Choose a level from 1 to 2 or type quit")
    if level == "1":
        a = random.randint (1, 10)
        b = random.randint (1, 10)
        answer = input(str(a) + " + " + str(b) + " = ")
        if int(answer) == a + b:
            print ("Good Job!")
        else:
            print ("Incorrect")
    if level == "2":
        a = random.randint (5, 20)
        b = random.randint (5, 20)
        answer = input(str(a) + " + " + str(b) + " = ")
        if int(answer) == a + b:
            print ("Good Job!")
        else:
            print ("Incorrect")
    if level == "quit":
        break
```

For what it's worth, you could have done some basic debugging yourself:

1. Try printing the answer and compare it to what you entered
2. Try printing the type
3. Print out the random numbers generated and their answer with the sum function.

Read about it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_input.asp)

Answer (score 1):

Convert the input "answer" to an int before checking whether the input is correct.
Currently, you code compares whether the string variable `answer` is equal to the integer `a + b` - which will evidently be False.

Change these rows:

```
if answer == a + b:
```

to

```
if int(answer) == a + b:
```

and it should work.